# ipython will not work even after reinstalling

Tags: ipython

Im trying very hard to get ipython notebook to work. I got it working in terminal, but I can't get it to work in my browser.

When I type ipython notebook in terminal, it says -bash: ipython: command not found

```
     MacBook-Air:~ me$ sudo easy_install https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tarball/master
     Downloading https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tarball/master
     error: None
     MacBook-Air:~ me$ ipython
     -bash: ipython: command not found
```

Im really unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to (and you probably shouldn't) do `sudo easy_install` it will probably install things as root, avoid `sudo`. Check that `ipython` executable is in **your** `$PATH`.
2. github tarballs are broken for IPython. You **do have to deep clone** with git if you want to run master, then run `python setup.py` with the option you like (install, develop, symlink)...
3. Use pip if you want to run IPython stable.
4. You might have issues with readline on osx (wrong multiline editting, wrong completion, IPython popping error messages at launch time) this is **one** of the **rare case** where you might **have to** using `easy_install` for readline.
5. Maverick (10.9) has issues with python/numpy/matplotlib you *might* need to have a custom python build with homebrew that does not use system libs.